# How to check if variable in a batch script has only new line?

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to exit from a batch script if `git status` is not empty:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion


FOR /F "tokens=*" %%g IN ('git status -s') do (SET GIT_STATUS=%%g)
(SET LF=^
%=this line is empty=%
)
IF "!GIT_STATUS!" NEQ "!LF!" ECHO (
  echo "ERROR: Git status is not empty: %GIT_STATUS%"
  goto END
)

:END
```

It prints error message even if the git status is clean. What can I try?

Comment: Use above __FOR__ command line `SET "GIT_STATUS="` to delete this environment variable if existing by chance. Change __FOR__ command line to `FOR /F "tokens=*" %%g IN ('git status -s') DO SET "GIT_STATUS=%%g"`. This command line takes output of git command line, removes all __leading__ spaces/tabs and assigns the rest of the last line to environment variable `GIT_STATUS` if something is assigned to loop variable `g` at all. It is not possible that just a line-feed or carriage return + line-feed is assigned to `g`. But it is possible that just a carriage return is assigned to loop variable `g`.

Comment: But `set "GIT_STATUS=%%g"` with a string consisting only of a carriage return results in deletion of environment variable `GIT_STATUS`. So after the __FOR__ command line it can be simply used `if defined GIT_STATUS echo ERROR: Git status is not empty: "%GIT_STATUS%"& goto END`. Open a command prompt window and run `for /?`, `goto /?`, `if /?` and `set /?` for help on the four internal commands of `cmd.exe` as used here. Delayed environment variable expansion is not needed for this task and should be better disabled to process also a git status correct containing `!` if that could ever occur.